# JS onload function not working using target _self or _top [codeigniter3] on select option element

Tags: javascript, window.open, onload-event, select-options

I'm creating view page named page "*review*" in codeigniter. and set the input value using JS `onload` function.

**I wana page to load in same widow**. but when I'm using `window.open(url,'_self')` or `window.open(url,'_top')` in JS code, the input value in element `<select>` on page "*review*" are't set.
however, `<select>` value are set or working when i'm using `window.open(url,'_blank')`

what should i do.?

some **view** code was error :

```
<div>
  <label>gender</label>
     <select id="gender" name="gender" required>
      <option value="">- select -</option>
      <option value="2">male</option>
      <option value="3">female</option>
    </select>
 </div>
```

my **JS** code placed in footer page :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.reviewBtn').click(function(){
     var dt0 = $(this).data('trans_code');
     var dt1 = $(this).data('status');
     var dt2 = $(this).data('gender');
     var pg1 = window.open('<?php echo base_url()?>trans/review/'+dt0,'_blank'); // input value set
     // var pg1 = window.open('<?php echo base_url()?>trans/review/'+dt0,'_self'); // input value not set
      pg1.onload = function(){
        if ( dt1 == "2" ) { // rejected
          pg1.document.getElementById('gender').value = dt2;
          pg1.document.getElementById('gender').required = false; // user could change
        } else {
          pg1.document.getElementById('gender').value = dt2;
          // user couldn't change
         }
      }
    });
  });
```

my **controller**

```
public function review($trans_code){ 
 $data['value']= $this->model->get_data($trans_code)->result(); // value = var to set another input value in review page
 $this->load->view('header');
 $this->load->view('review',$data);
 $this->load->view('footer');
}
```

Comment: When you're loading a new page to the window, all the code execution on the previous page is stopped, and all the pending events are aborted. You've to rethink the logic, and set the values on the server or in JS of the new page.

Comment: thanks @Teemu, finally i solve this problem.
i move JS script `window.onload` to a new page _review_,
`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally I solve this problem. I break JS code in to two part. first I move JS script `window.onload` to a new page *review*. I retrieve *gender value* using **php** code, `foreach($value as $dt)` to obtained value  from *modal* result

```
window.onload = function(){
  var dt0 = <?php echo $dt->trans_status?>;
  var dt1 = <?php echo $dt->cust_gender?>;
    if ( dt0 == "2" ) { // rejected
      document.getElementById('gender').value = dt1;
      document.getElementById('gender').required = false; // user could change
    } else {
        document.getElementById('gender').value = dt2;
          // user couldn't change
     }
}
```

second, modified JS code in footer

```
$('.reviewBtn').click(function(){
     var dt0 = $(this).data('trans_code');
     window.open('<?php echo base_url()?>trans/review/'+dt0,'_self'); 
});
```

and `<select>` value was set successfully.